# og:image not being updated when browsing different youtube videos

Tags: youtube

I seen something strange when browsing youtube videos. The og:image does not change as I keep browsing from one page to another. The og:image always points to the first youtube video. Of course, if I manually refresh the page, I see the correct og:image information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOUTUBE use nodejs for their site. Nodejs is a javascript enable server site script, as nodejs is a non blocking code, that means it first updates that part of webpage which takes less time to execute and vice versa.`og:image` contains, default video thumbnail. You can use url of thumbnail to get og:image.

For the high quality version of the thumbnail use a url similar to this:

```
https://ytimg.googleusercontent.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/hqdefault.jpg
```

For videos which have high quality you can use below url. For HQ videos.

For the maximum resolution version of the thumbnail use a url similar to this:

```
https://ytimg.googleusercontent.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/maxresdefault.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I do think I can use the video ID to determine the image. However, I was wondering why the og:image does not actually update as I browse different videos on the site and if there was a way to force update. It remains as the og:image of the first video.

Comment: @AshD I have write that, it uses nodejs, non blocking code and youtube configure its server, that it changes only that part of webpage which belongs to user expectation(videos, related videos,comments), og:image does not make any thing for a normal user, it belongs to developers.

Comment: Thank you again. Would you know if there is any general way to programmatically get the actual (updated) og:image data and such, not just for youtube but for other sites as well that employ a similar tactic?

Comment: @AshD Sorry for late reply, use jquery .load() to update a particular web page part.